# Jenkins: Monitoring for JUnit test execution time?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, monitoring

In order to prevent performance degradation in my project, I would like to introduce some monitoring on the runtime of JUnit tests in jenkins. Ideally, I would like to see the execution time of tests over time as a diagram in Jenkins (i.e. a test execution time trend graph). The runtime of a single test (or test category) over time would also be interesting. RAM usage monitoring per test would be a nice-to-have too. I've seen some approaches online, people even go as far as using the SonarQube plugin just to have this kind of test execution time monitoring.

**My question is:** how do you tackle this problem? It seems like a very basic and straight-forward thing to do, but there doesn't seem to be a clear solution in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stage View plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) can provide insight in the timing of various stages, and something like the [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) can be used to plot data across builds.

Wiring these two together seems like a plausible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JMeter Plugin an have this kind of tracking, it's not the same, but it  helps me a lot for the Quick testing of tha API's
[image]

Comment: Nice, but isn't JMeter for web applications only? I'm looking for a similar solution, except for general JUnit tests (not necessarily webapps).